# How do I monitor Internet download volume to my LAN

Tags: mac, networking, monitoring

I have a satellite-connected modem for internet access: a (wifi+wire) router is connected to this, and provides access to a LAN with several Macs, 2 windows boxes, and an Ubuntu machine. Most connections are via wifi. One of the Macs on the network is a Mac Pro which has two NICs, only one of which is being used.

I would like to monitor download volume from the internet: ie what contributes to my download cap from my ISP. What's the best way of doing this?

Regards,
David

Answer (score 3):

The most accurate way would probably be to get a router that supports bandwidth monitoring - You can also (potentially) use DD-WRT firmware on your existing router which allows you to monitor the bandwidth being used (along with a host of other enhanced features).

You can also monitor usage using software on your computers, but inadequacies are likely to develop as it doesn't necessarily account for all traffic - particularly if you or a friend adds another machine/mobile device/tablet/etc to the network temporarily.

Here is (1) [a list of routers supported by DD-WRT](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Supported_Devices) (2) [a guide on installing DD-WRT on your router](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Installation) and (3) [here is a guide on enabling bandwidth monitoring](http://www.simplehelp.net/2008/09/11/how-to-use-the-dd-wrt-firmware-to-monitor-your-bandwidth/).

Comment: My router supports bandwidth monitoring, but - like the software I've looked at - it appears that **all** traffic, including local LAN traffic, would be included. Does the DD-WRT firmware support the differentiation?

Comment: Yes, it does differentiate